# Git merge exported copy with original repository

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-merge

From an original repository with commits `A, B, C, D` there is an exported copy from commit `B`. What's the best way for the copied repository to get the latest changes `C, D` from the original repository?

**EDIT**: By *exported*  I mean a copy-paste of the non-git files from commit `B` into a new empty git repository, thereby not preserving the history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like answer from Jonathan.Brink but in case you can set up your other repo as remote (do not have ssh or so one) you could create and apply a patch.

I am not sure if you can create a patch from a given commit (if you give a commit id to the command, it will patch all until the commit) but you can do

```
git format-patch master -1 A --stdout > commitA.patch
git format-patch master -1 B --stdout > commitB.patch
```

Then you can apply those patches on the other repository

```
git apply --stat <commit.patch_files>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the exported copy is still a Git repo you could define a remote to the other repository and merge it in:

```
git add remote OtherRepo <url>
git fetch OtherRepo
git merge OtherRepo/otherBranch
```

Comment: That works if the repository is copied with complete history. By exported I mean a copy of the repo from commit `B` without history (e.g., a copy and paste excluding the .git directory)

Comment: @JohanSjöberg in that case it's probably better to work with individual patches as in Frederic's answer